# React Context with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

Currently, I am leaning React!
And our team has committed to using `Typescript`.

I am in a state where I need to implement a shopping cart for a shopping mall.
And since the shopping cart is used in the product list, header, detail page, and the shopping cart page itself.
So I want to use React.Context.

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const CartProvider = (props: any) => {
    const addItemToCartHandler = (item: object) => {};
    const removeItemFromCartHandler = (id: string) => {};

    const CartContext = createContext({
        items: [
            {
                name: 'product-1',
                price: 450000,
                quantity: 1,
                images: [
                    'https://www-prd-kr.gentlemonster.com/media/catalog/product/cache/6c6f229b8a7ab97f51028776641e27d1/1/1/11001_PASO_BL3_2_1.jpg',
                ],
            },
        ],
        totalQuantity: 0,
        addItem: addItemToCartHandler,
        removeItem: removeItemFromCartHandler,
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CartContext.Provider value={CartContext}>{props.children}</CartContext.Provider>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default CartProvider;
```

Since it is still before API development, I will try to implement data distribution first.
The idea was to put data in the context default value
and put the value through a variable in the shopping cart.

Error1. Argument of type `(props: any) => JSX.Element` is not assignable to parameter of type `Context<unknown>`.

Error2. Type `Context<{ items: never[]; totalQuantity: number; addItem: (item: object) => void; removeItem: (id: string) => void; }>` is missing the following properties from type `{ items: never[]; totalQuantity: number; addItem: (item: object) => void; removeItem: (id: string) => void; }': items, totalQuantity, addItem, removeItem`

How can I fix this error?

I tried to set the type for each data object property.

Answer (score 1):

> `Error1. Argument of type '(props: any) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context'.`

I think this is just a strict rule where TS want you to specify which functions is a React component. You can do that by adding the React type to make TS happy with

```
const CartProvider: React.FC<{ props: any }> = (props: any) => {
```

> `Error2. Type 'Context<{ items: never[]; totalQuantity: number; addItem: (item: object) => void; removeItem: (id: string) => void; }>' is missing the following properties from type '{ items: never[]; totalQuantity: number; addItem: (item: object) => void; removeItem: (id: string) => void; }': items, totalQuantity, addItem, removeItem`

In TS, you are supposed to initialize `Context` with a value that TS can automatically extract. In this case what you had is a bit too random for TS to automatically match what you are passing to context value.

In my personal experience, it's far easier to manage the types in Context API by initialize the Context with dummy value, then apply the initial values where you are calling them from with the `props`.

Anyways, here is the complete code that should get rid of all errors:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react'

const addItemToCartHandler = (item: object) => {}
const removeItemFromCartHandler = (id: string) => {}

type item = { // optional
  name: string
  price: number
  quantity: number
  images: string[]
}

const CartContext = createContext({
  items: [] as item[], // `as item[]` part is optional
  totalQuantity: NaN,
  addItem: (item: object) => undefined,
  removeItem: (id: string) => undefined
})

const CartProvider: React.FC<{ props: any }> = (props: any) => {
  const contextValue = {
    items: [
      {
        name: 'product-1',
        price: 450000,
        quantity: 1,
        images: [
          'https://www-prd-kr.gentlemonster.com/media/catalog/product/cache/6c6f229b8a7ab97f51028776641e27d1/1/1/11001_PASO_BL3_2_1.jpg'
        ]
      }
    ],
    totalQuantity: 0,
    addItem: addItemToCartHandler,
    removeItem: removeItemFromCartHandler
  }

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default CartProvider
```

Cheers